# How can I convert CodeIgniter result array to a numeric array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I was wondering, How can I convert codeigniter query result array to a numeric array?

Should I iterate the whole result array and make a new numeric array or Is there efficient way?

Thank you

Comment: try being more specific about what you want, showing as what you've tried

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question but the return from `db->result()` is already a numeric array.

Comment: Please post your table structure and expected result.

Comment: what do you mean by numeric array ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example for your requirement from documentation,

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['body'];
}
```